# How to change the color of text view from adapter, textView's background is defined in drawable

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my text view in layout.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCharacter"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_43sdp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1.8"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_1sdp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_1sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_textview"
    android:text="H"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_28ssp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

This is the background, for text view to implement a circle shape

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/circle" />
```

and this is circle.xml file and here is the background color of textView which I want to change

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">

<solid android:color="#9FE554" />

<stroke
    android:width="0dp"
    android:color="#000" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done this by using the following code and used Random color all the times

```
Random r = new Random();
        int red=r.nextInt(255 - 0 + 1)+0;
        int green=r.nextInt(255 - 0 + 1)+0;
        int blue=r.nextInt(255 - 0 + 1)+0;
        int alpha = 200;

        GradientDrawable draw = new GradientDrawable();
        draw.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
        draw.setColor(Color.argb(alpha,red,green,blue));
        viewHolder.tvCharacter.setBackground(draw);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the drawable, then use `setColorFilter` method to change its color and finally set new background to your TextView:

```
Drawable drawable = itemView.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle);
drawable.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.getContext(), R.color.colorPrimary),
                            PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
tvCharacter.setBackground(drawable);
```

I don't think you need @drawable/rounded_textview in this case. I would set the TextView background to @drawable/circle.

Note: I'm using `itemView.getContext()` because I implemented this in the constructor of ViewHolder.